# How to insert / transplant columns from one dataframe to another at a certain position?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
print(df1)

   A  B  C
0  1  5  9
1  2  6  8
2  3  7  7
3  4  8  6


print(df2)

   D  E  F
0  1  5  9
1  2  6  8
2  3  7  7
3  4  8  6
```

I want to insert columns `D` and `E` from `df2` into `df1` after column `B`.

The end result should be like this:

```
   A  B  D  E  C
0  1  5  1  5  9
1  2  6  2  6  8
2  3  7  3  7  7
3  4  8  4  8  6
```

I know there's already a solution with the `insert` method with pandas:

`df1.insert(1, "D", df2["D"])`
`df1.insert(2, "E", df2["E"])`

However I would like to insert `D` and `E` at the same time. Like "transplant" it into `df1`, rather than having multiple inserts. (in real life the data to be transplanted is bigger which is why I want to avoid all the inserts)

My dataframes in dict format, so you can use DataFrame.from_dict():

```
# df1

{'A': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
 'B': {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 7, 3: 8},
 'C': {0: 9, 1: 8, 2: 7, 3: 6}}

# df2

{'D': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
 'E': {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 7, 3: 8},
 'F': {0: 9, 1: 8, 2: 7, 3: 6}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice the dataframe `df1` into two parts based on the location of column `B`, then `concat` these slices with columns `D, E` along the columns axis

```
i = df1.columns.get_loc('B') + 1
pd.concat([df1.iloc[:, :i], df2[['D', 'E']], df1.iloc[:, i:]], axis=1)
```

---

```
   A  B  D  E  C
0  1  5  1  5  9
1  2  6  2  6  8
2  3  7  3  7  7
3  4  8  4  8  6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is optimal. Alternatively you can:

```
df1[["D", "E"]] = df2[["D", "E"]]
```

and then change the column order

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
 'B': {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 7, 3: 8},
 'C': {0: 9, 1: 8, 2: 7, 3: 6}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'D': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
 'E': {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 7, 3: 8},
 'F': {0: 9, 1: 8, 2: 7, 3: 6}})

df1.merge(df2[['D', 'E']],on=df1.index)
```

You can reorder based on your requirement